# Get extension object in gnome-shell

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gjs

I'm working on a gnome-shell extension. I was wondering if I can get the object of *other* extensions.

I only find the means to get the current extension object using 
`ExtensionUtils.getCurrentExtension()`

Is there any possibility to access other installed extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're on GNOME 3.4 judging by the `ExtensionUtils.getCurrentExtension()` (not available in 3.2).

Do `ExtensionUtils.extensions[other_extensions_uuid]` to get the other extension's object (init, enable and disable function plus any of its global variables/functions/classes).